# Extract Word match from column in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data frame in which one of the column is of the form

```
Mat_Headers_Turbine = df_2['1'].unique().tolist()
print(Mat_Headers_Turbine)

['TURBINE , GAS ', 'TURBINE ', 'TURBINE,STEAM ', 'TURBINE, STEAM ', 'TURBINE,EXPANSION ', 'TURBINE STEAM ', 'STEAM TURBINE ', 'TURATING ', 'PUMPS, RECIPROCATING ', 'BLOWERS ', 'REGENERATOR CYLONE SEPERATOR ', 'MOBILE CRANE ', 'MECHANICAL SEAL ', 'TOOLS - MISCELLANEOUS', 'LADDERS ', 'TRANSDUCER ', 'FLAME SCANNERS AND PARTS:', 'VALVE, CONTROL, GLOBE ']
```

I only need to extract the corresponding value to "TURBINE" which is "gas/steam/air/engine/expansion into a new column.
The no. of rows are around 50,000. How can i do this ?

Comment: `df_2.loc[df_2['1'].isin([<all_the_options>])]` should do for you

Comment: isin will not work because the text if of the form [Turbine , Gas] in one single cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to use the following pandas query

```
turbine_values = df_2[(df_2['1'].notnull()) & (df_2['1'].str.contains('TURBINE'))]['1'].apply(lambda turbine_string: turbine_string.split(',')[-1].strip())
```

This will bring all rows that contains `'TURBINE'` on the desired column and then the corresponding value.

Comment: thank you for your reply.                                                                                                         ` turbine_values = df_2[df_2['Mat Header'].str.contains('TURBINE')]['Mat Header'].apply(lambda turbine_string: turbine_string.split(',')[-1].strip())
print(df_2[turbine_values]) ` Getting error **ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values**

Comment: I changed the query to get rows that are not null

Comment: the query works **GAS ; MAKE: M/S HITACHI ; MODEL: H-25 ** in stripping "Turbine" but i just need "GAS" and want to get rid of the rest....

Comment: if you want the "GAS", make another query in `turbine_values`. Like this `turbine_values = turbine_values[turbine_values.contains('GAS')]`